# Regex match certain amount of character and allow space inbetween

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently working on a regex which needs to match exactly 8 digits. But sometimes it occurs that there are spaces or dots between those numbers. This is the regex that i am currently using.

```
([0-9\ ?.?]{7,16})
```

It works fine most of the time, but the problem I am having is that it sometimes matches number with a lot of spaces tailing it so you will get something like 1234/s/s/s/s (/s stands for space) Or sometimes it is only matching spaces.

What i want is a regex that always matches at least 8 digits and also allows spaces and dots without detecting less then 8 digits. I know it may be stupid question, but I couldn't find anything I need elswhere.

Comment: So, *match **exactly** 8 digits* or *a regex that always matches **at least** 8 digits*?

Comment: Why not replace everything other than digits with empty string and check the  length of the new String?

Comment: it has to be extactly 8 digits

Comment: I forgot to tell that I am pulling the text from html source code so thats where I need to match my Regex

Comment: Try `(?<!\d[ .]?)\d(?:[. ]?\d){7}(?![ .]?\d)`. Is the number of periods or spaces limited to 0-1 or can there be more in between the digits? In case there can be more, try using [`(?<!\d[ .]*)\d(?:[ .]*\d){7}(?![ .]*\d)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cd%5b+.%5d*%29%5cd%28%3f%3a%5b+.%5d*%5cd%29%7b7%7d%28%3f!%5b+.%5d*%5cd%29&i=12345678%0d%0a1+23+45+67+8%0d%0a%0d%0a+erw+4.35.645.74+dwe).

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments, I can certaintly work with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `([0-9\ ?.?]{7,16})` expression matches 7 to 16 occurrences of any character that is either a digit, or a space, or a `?`, or `.`. Yes, the `?` inside `[...]` is a literal `?`, not a quantifier.

You need to use an expression that will match a digit (`[0-9]`) and then exactly 7 sequences of a space or period (`[ .]`) followed with 1 digit, and to make sure you are not matching the digits in `123.156.78.146` you may use special boundaries:

```
(?<!\d[ .]?)\d(?:[. ]?\d){7}(?![ .]?\d)
```

if the space or `.` can only be 0 to 1 in between digits; or - if the space/dot can appear 0 or more times,

```
(?<!\d[ .]*)\d(?:[. ]*\d){7}(?![ .]*\d)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%5B%20.%5D%2A%29%5Cd%28%3F%3A%5B%20.%5D%2A%5Cd%29%7B7%7D%28%3F!%5B%20.%5D%2A%5Cd%29&i=12345678%0D%0A1%2023%2045%2067%208%0D%0A%0D%0A%20erw%204.35.645.74%20dwe)

The `(?<!\d[ .]*)` is a negative lookbehind that will fail any match if it starts with a digit that is followed with `.`(s) or space(s), and the `(?![ .]*\d)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the 7 digits you need are followed with `.`(s) or space(s) and a digit.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, describe the problem to yourself. You want to match one digit followed by seven repetitions of space-or-dot followed by a digit. This leads to a regular expression like `\d([ .]?\d){7}`. To avoid collecting the seven captures add a `:?` after the `(`. To capture the whole string, enclose it in brackets. Adding both changes gives the expression `(\d(:?[ .]?\d){7})`. If more than one space or dot is allowed between the digits then change the `?` to a `*`.

To get just the eight digits out of the string I suggest using the string captured above and replacing any spaces or dots with nothing.